# Error:candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

I have created a class file "Heuristic.hpp" with the following definition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include "csv.hpp"
#include "mdl.hpp"

class Computation {

public:

     Computation(const int n,const int noRows, MDL mdl) {


        std::cout << "Constructor successfully made" << std::endl;
    }

    double heuristic() {
        return 0;
    }


private:

    std::vector<uint64_t> MDL_RawIndex_;
    std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> factValues_;
    std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> MDL_Index_;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> MDL_RawScore_;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> MDL_Score_;
    std::vector<uint64_t> MDL_Score_Length_;
    std::vector<double> bestScore_;

    int n_ = 0;
    int noRows_ = 0;

};
```

And on the main code file "example.cpp" when I try to create the object its throwing me error. The code as follows: the error when I try to create the object of the class Computation declared in the previous file. The constructor isnt being called in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "csv.hpp"
#include "mdl.hpp"
#include "Heuristic.hpp"

Computation bootup() {
    std::string in = "/Users/skx/Google Drive/Semester3_Fall15/CSE603/HeuristicSearchPy/child.csv";
    int noRows = 4000;
    std::vector<signed char> Data;
    int n = 20;

    if (!read_csv(in, n, noRows, Data)) {
        std::cout << "error: could not read input" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    MDL mdl(n, noRows, Data);

    Computation h(n,noRows,mdl);   //This object creation is where error is occurring 
    return h;
    }


int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {


return 0;
}
```

Error log:

```
note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'Computation &&' for 1st argument
class Computation {
      ^
/Users/skx/Google Drive/Semester3_Fall15/CSE603/HeuristicSearchPy/Heuristic.hpp:11:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const Computation &' for 1st argument
class Computation {
```

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: Is it `Computation` or `MDL` that is supposed to be constructed?

Comment: Computation has to be constructed(Causes the error) , MDL has been constructed (working fine)

Comment: That's still not the full error message. It will most likely start with something like this **error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'Computation'** and just before this it will have the filename and line number. As @sheltond mentioned in his answer, if you look closely at that line number you will most likely find that the error is not where you think it is.

Comment: Probably, you can rename the header file to the class name and add the header guards.  Like: #ifndef Computation_HPP #define Computation and at the end of file #endif . You can learn about it more from http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the line number causing the problem in the error message, so this is just a guess, but I think the problem is on the "return -1" line.

It's trying to find a constructor with a single argument, and the only ones that it can find are the implicit copy and move constructors. The error message is telling you that it tried to use these, but couldn't convert from type "int" (the -1) to "Computation".